# webgl2 with premultipliedAlpha:false and unwanted edges

Tags: webgl2, premultiplied-alpha

I am trying to craft a very simple webgl demo with `premultipliedAlpha:false`. However I am having hard times getting rid of the unwanted dark pixels around the drawn triangles edges. I need this webgl to be `premultipliedAlpha:false` and `alpha:true` but can not figure out what is the missing piece:

I have tried with:

- `outColor.rgb /= outColor.a` in fragment shader
- `gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);`
- different combinations of `gl.clearColor()`, `gl.colorMask()`, `gl.clear()`
- `gl.blendFunc()`

but so far now luck.

Here is the html

```html
<body>
<canvas id="canvasWebgl" width="256" height="256" style="background-color: red;"></canvas>
<script>

const canvasWebgl = document.getElementById("canvasWebgl");

var vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
in vec2 a_position;
out vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
    vec2 clipSpace = (a_position * 2.0) - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
    v_texCoord = a_position;
}`;

var fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
in vec2 v_texCoord;
out vec4 outColor;
void main() {
    outColor = texture(u_image, v_texCoord);
}`;

function createShader(source, type) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    return shader;
}

function drawPoints(points, color) {
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(color));
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length/2);
}

const gl = canvasWebgl.getContext("webgl2", {premultipliedAlpha:false});

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.createTexture());
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

const program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, createShader(vertexShaderSource, gl.VERTEX_SHADER));
gl.attachShader(program, createShader(fragmentShaderSource, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER));
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);

const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

drawPoints([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 255, 0, 0]);
drawPoints([.3, .3, 1, .4, .4, 1], [255, 0, 0, 255]);
</script>
</body>
```

and the rendered output:

[image: unwanted edges]